# Identify which key to modify

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm using a SESSION variable to hold items added to an ingredients page. I'm wondering how I can uniquely identify each key in the array.

I'm adding ingredients via the following and it's working fine.

```
$_SESSION['ingredients'][] = array($_POST['ingredient'],$_POST['qty']);
```

If I stick a few ingredients in there and print the array I get..

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 50 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 50 ) Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 50 )
```

Where 1, 2 and 3 are the ingredient IDs.

I can remove ingredients from the array based on their ID no problem, but if I put the same ingredient in twice I won't be able to distinguish between them. I was wondering if I can add an incremental number to ID the key?

Comment: How do you add and remove them?  Is there a form to go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the items in $_SESSION['ingredients'] already has a unique index (starting from 0 in your case). When you print your $_SESSION['ingredients'] array, you should get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 20 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 10 ) )
```

Notice that each array combination has an index preceding it (starting at 0)

The following code demonstrates this:

```
<?php

session_start();
unset($_SESSION['ingredients']);

$_SESSION['ingredients'][] = array(1, 20);
$_SESSION['ingredients'][] = array(2, 20);
$_SESSION['ingredients'][] = array(1, 10); // adding the same ingredient again

print_r($_SESSION['ingredients']);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was printing the array after I had split it via $rows. Oopsie.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the ingredient id as the key in the session array and then append each value to it as an element

```
$_SESSION['ingredients'][$_POST['ingredient']][] = $_POST['qty'];
```

This would give you

```
Array(
    [1] => array(
        [0] => 50,
        [1] => 50
    )

)
```

Just a thought, I don't know if this would work for your use case

Answer (score -1):

change your inserted array to this:

```
$_SESSION['ingredients'][count($_SESSION['ingredients'])] = array($_POST['ingredient'],$_POST['qty']);
```

I use it in my program.

Comment: What's the actual difference?

Comment: This actually does not make a any difference to OP's solutions. The indexes will be the same in both approaches!